# Read Custom Header from https request redirected to IBM BPM 8.5.7

Tags: business-process-management

I am routing IBM BPM Process Portal URL from custom portal, when I Log in to custom portal it stores user ID and password in custom http header.
IBM BPM Process Portal not able to understand custom http header and shows login page to authenticate user again.
Is it possible to read custom http header in Process Portal in IBM BPM Std 8.5.7, so it will work like SSO.

Please suggest.

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not so much a "portal" problem as a "WebSphere" problem.  The WebSphere container is in charge of authenticating the user.  That is when a request comes in to an IBM BPM URL, the BPM code asks WebSphere "Hey, is this request authenticated?"  If the answer is yes, it allows the user to get to the URL.  If the answer is no, it does whatever WebSphere has been told is the right next action for an unauthenticated user requests.

What you really need is a "Trust Authentication Interceptor" or TAI.  This is a piece of software you add to WebSphere that can use a different mechanism from the standard login page to Authenticate the user to the WAS container.  If the other software is using a standard SSO technology then it maybe that the software creator already has a TAI you can install.  If it is a "roll your own" solution someone needs to write one.

You can easily find many articles from IBM on how to write a TAI.  [Here](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/SG246573/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=SG246573&file=14-15.htm) is an IBM Redbook I found that touches on the topic.

-AP